# Flutter + Firebase | java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to complete a very simple exercise by **connecting** my basic **Flutter** app **to Cloud Firestore** (in Firebase).

I have followed the instructions with regards to setup. However, I am getting the following error.

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(13217): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(13217): java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist.
```

My flutter code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Playground',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Playground App'),
            ),
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Text('Sup World?'),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('test').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading....');

                return Text('Loaded');
              },
            )
            ])));
  }
}
```

Dependencies in the android\build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}
```

Dependencies and new lines added in the android\app\build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Dependencies in the pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.15.7
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2
```

I've also downloaded and added the **google-services.json** file to the android\app folder.

In the Firestore db, I have a collection with id **test** containing one document.

Expected result:
The text "Loaded" should appear under the text "Sup World?"

However, I am getting the above error and it's showing the text "Loading".

Could someone help in getting this resolved please?

Comment: It would be nice if you add pubspec file also such that we can know whether have you added firebase plugin in flutter pubspec.yaml!! And cross check whether you have added classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' in your project level gradle.

Comment: @Harshapulikollu - i have updated the thread with the dependencies from the pubspec.yaml file.

Comment: @Harshapulikollu - regarding project level gradle, do you mean a gradle file at the flutter project level? I don't have one in mine.

Comment: I mean in your android project level. <flutter project>/android/build.gradle file

Comment: @Harshapulikollu - yes its in there. I have added it already above. Putting it here again in case it helps:
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
}

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `google-services.json` file?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - the google-services.json file is in the android\app folder

Comment: I assume you are running it on an Android device/emulator, right?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - that's correct - thanks for your suggestion on GitHub. It's resolved now!

Answer (score 2):

I had posted this on GitHub as well. Running flutter clean on the project and then running the app again fixed it for me.

The url to the GitHub issue.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28003

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I updated to newer google-services.

Switched back to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'` and it started working fine.